# Pass hidden value in rewritten URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, hidden

Just wondering if there is a way to pass a hidden variable in a rewritten URL?

My links are working fine with this format:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/city/state/businessname/
```

But I'd also like to be able to get and pass the businessID value, but not have it show up in the rewritten link.

http://www.mydomain.com/city/state/businessname/***busid***/ <- hide busid

Answer (score 1):

If the businessId should not appear in the frontend url then you can retrieve it in the controller / action that is handling this request.

ie. If you can get the businessid from the businessname, there is no need to retrieve it and then rewrite url, just do that logic in your controller action.

Or setup a Filter or Interceptor to handle it.

Comment: I can get the business name fine, but in some cases there may be two of the same business name in the listing, but both businesses would have different IDs.

Comment: Then how can you know which business id this: `http://www.mydomain.com/city/state/businessname/` maps to?

Comment: Right now I'm looking up the business name in the database and matching it to the business ID, the problem occurs when there are more than one business with the same name in the same town.

Comment: Indeed, which is why that URL structure wont work. If you want this front facing url: http://www.mydomain.com/city/state/businessname/ then you have to know what page to load based on that. You need to have a unique ID in the URL, or make state and businessname unique. E.g. 
businessname-1 businessname-2 or /businessname/1342

Comment: Sounds good, thanks cowls for the input!  Now that I've got htaccess working the possibilities are endless!  Just gotta work out the best way to handle it. 

Thanks again!